Writing the definition of Upper Bound

Let X be an ordered set. Let $ S \subset X.$ An element $ u \in X$ is said to be an upper bound for $S$ if $s \leq u$ for all $ s \in S.$

In first-order logic, how do I write the above definition? Is it something like this?
$\forall u \in X\quad($$(\forall s \in S$, $s \leq u)$$\implies$$u$ is an upper bound for $S).$



Let $X$ be an ordered set. Let $ S \subset X.$ An element $ u \in X$ is
said to be an upper bound for $S$ if $s \leq u$ for all $ s \in S.$

In first-order logic, how do I write the above definition?

Let $u$ and $S$ be an element and a subset, respectively, of an ordered set $X.$ Then $$u \text{ is an upper bound for }S\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}\;\forall s{\in}S\;s \leq u.$$

Reply to comment

What is the quantifier for $u$? Do we need one here? Without a quantifier isn’t $u$ free?

The text preceding the definition (which follows the word "Then") of the statement "$u$ is an upper bound of $S$" has already introduced the objects $u, S$ and $X,$ so they are not free variables. But, sure, we can insist on formalising even that prefacing text:
$$\forall u\forall S\Big(\big(\exists X\:(X \text{ is an ordered set and } u\in X\text{ and } S\subset X)\big)\\\implies\big(u \text{ is an upper bound for }S\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}\;\forall s{\in}S\;s \leq u\big)\Big),$$ or, equivalently,
$$\forall u\forall S\forall X\Big(\big(X \text{ is an ordered set and } u\in X\text{ and } S\subset X\big)\\\implies\big(u \text{ is an upper bound for }S\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}\;\forall s{\in}S\;s \leq u\big)\Big).$$

What is the quantifier for u? Do we need one here? Without a quantifier isn’t u free?

Thank you! Would the set S need a quantifier also?

@Dr.J Isn't that already in the addendum? But really , that preface isn't part of the definition's meat, just as Q: Explain what 'girl' means.  A: Okay, for every object called 'girl', "I am a girl" means "I am a young woman" contains a superfluous quantification.

I see. I know you stated S wouldn’t be free. I was just wondering if there was any reason there wasn’t a quantifier for S where you were formalizing the prefacing text. But your example makes sense. Thank you!

sorry I was meaning the set S, S $\subset$ X not the elements s. Did we need a quantifier for the set S because we have S $\subset$ X?

@Dr.J Oh, in the addednum, I'd mistyped the first instance of 'S' as 's'. Corrected now; thanks!
